# Regex to match number after 3 numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

i made this regex to match the number after 3 numbers:

```
var text = 'RAT 56.367,41 0,00 0,00 0,00 56.367,41';
var reg  = /RAT\s(?:\d\S*\s+){4}(\d\S*)/g;

var match = text.match(reg);
console.log(match[0]);
```

I want capture the last 56.367,41, but is returning:

```
RAT 56.367,41 0,00 0,00 0,00 56.367,41
```

How could i improve this to achieve what i need?

Also, i can't really change the explicity RAT name, because this tiny piece is just a part of a huge text.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the value always single in a given string? Can you omit `g`?

Comment: @AmandaFerrari: why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong method. If you want to retrieve the value, try `exec` instead. Here is the full code:

```
var text = 'RAT 56.367,41 0,00 0,00 0,00 56.367,41';
var reg  = /RAT\s(?:\d\S*\s+){4}(\d\S*)/g;
var match = reg.exec(text);
console.log(match[1]);
```

Comment: yep, thats is that i need!

Answer (score 0):

You can grab first capturing group in a while loop:

```
var re = /RAT\s(?:\d\S*\s+){4}(\d\S*)/g; 
var str = 'RAT 56.367,41 0,00 0,00 0,00 56.367,41';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex)
        re.lastIndex++;
    console.log(m[1]);
}

//=> 56.367,41
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pU2jT4/1)